# Django case insensitive login, mixed case username

Tags: django

I'm trying to do case insensitive login for a Django app, without altering original username case. According to my research, the best approach is to create a related field to store the username in lowercase at registration. No reinventing the user model, it's a simple solution, right? My dilemma: How to do you take data from one model, change it, and save it in another model when the object is created?

Here is what is in **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    lc_n = User.username
    lc_n = lc_n.lower()
    lowercase_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=lc_n)
```

When running `python manage.py makemigrations` there is the following error:

`AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'username'`

User does have that attribute, but it can't be accessed this way.

Please forgive me, as this must contain some simple fundamental flaw. Any support that may be offered will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need any additional models to implement case insensitive login.  Django supports case insensitive filtering by `iexact` operator:

```
user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=name)
```

Comment: I did find an example that used this very method. In the comments below the example, someone said "This won’t use Django’s index on username and will do a seqscan of the database instead, which is very slow with many users. You should either create an index or lowercase all usernames upon creation and search for those." I'm quite ignorant here, so I accepted his word. Is his statement correct? http://www.shopfiber.com/case-insensitive-username-login-in-django/

Comment: In retrospect, it appears that your solution does indeed query only the username index and is quite straightforward. It seems that the fellow I quoted earlier may have made a troll's meal out of me.

Comment: I'm using Django 1.7, with the django-registration-redux extension, which already prevents duplicate, different case usernames, so no problem there. In django/contrib/auth/models.py in the class BaseUserManager, I set get_by_natural_key() to `return self.get(username__iexact=username)` and it is working well. Thank you!